# Apresentar valores que constam numa tabela mas não na outra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia.
Sou novo na parte de Base de dados e em SQL e estou com uma dúvida num exercício da faculdade. 
O objetivo do exercício é:

[image: QL]

Consegui fazer a parte de apresentar o número, descrição da conta, nome do fornecedor e localidade, contudo apresenta-me todos os valores e pretendo apenas aqueles em que as contas balanço não constam em nenhuma fatura porém não estou a conseguir fazer essa parte.
Junto envio código

```
select NúmeroConta, Descrição, Nome, Localidade
from  ContasBalanço join Fornecedores
on ContasBalanço.NúmeroConta = Fornecedores.ContaBalançoPredefinida join Facturas
on Fornecedores.IDFornecedor = Facturas.Fornecedor
where
```

Na minha opinião, penso que a condição que falta adicionar é no Where contudo não sei como fazer essa parte. 
Junto deixo também foto das tabelas.

Contas Balanço:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fornecedores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faturas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ItensFaturas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradecia imenso se alguém me conseguisse ajudar. Tal como disse sou novo nisto e estou a gostar de aprender base de dados e acho isto interessante, contudo surgiu me este pequeno problema e não sei como resolver.
Cumprimentos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para compreender mais sobre Joins, recomendo ler [este artigo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006) ou [este outro](https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/joins-em-sql).

Basicamente, o que você precisa é de todos os dados de uma tabela(Contas Balanço) enquanto precisa apenas verificar a outra(Fatura) para selecionar os dados requisitados, nesse caso o ideal seria fazer um **left join**, assim o script ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
select NúmeroConta, Descrição, Nome, Localidade
from  ContasBalanço join Fornecedores
on ContasBalanço.NúmeroConta = Fornecedores.ContaBalançoPredefinida 
left join Facturas
on Fornecedores.IDFornecedor = Facturas.Fornecedor
where 
Facturas.IDFactura is null
ORDER BY ContasBalanço.NúmeroConta;
```

Outra solução para um problema semelhante pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/sql-para-registros-que-nao-estao-em-outra-tabela/284709).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Percebi que havia um erro no meu script, então editei a resposta, caso teste e não funcione, por favor comente aqui!

Comment: O seu script funciona, e muito obrigado por me estar a ajudar. Também dei conta que faltava uma tabela na pergunta que coloquei. As contas balanço só devem ser apresentadas se não houver nenhum registo em ItensFaturas e não em Faturas. Contudo, penso que ItensFaturas está dependente de Faturas. Inicialmente pensei em utilizar o seu código mas substituir Faturas por ItensFaturas mas logo percebi que não dava pois são dependentes. Como é que poderei fazer?

Comment: Editei novamente a resposta, verifique se agora o retorno está adequado.

Comment: Já consegui resolver. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Bastou adicionar Left join Facturas e a condição on ......... e funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Vou te dar algumas dicas, primeiramente você deve organizar o seu código deixar bem estruturado de forma que você consiga ler as informações com mais facilidade:

```
SELECT cbal.NúmeroConta, cbal.Descrição, forn.Nome, forn.Localidade
FROM ContasBalanço cbal
  INNER JOIN facturasacturas fac
    ON fac.ContaBalançoPredefinida = cbal.NúmeroConta
  INNER JOIN Fornecedores forn
    ON forn.IDFornecedor = fac.Fornecedor
ORDER BY cbal.NúmeroConta ASC
```

Veja como separei as linhas, **SELECT**, **FROM**, **INNER**, **ON**, **ORDER BY**.

Quando uma coisa pertence a outra como o **ON** no **INNER** eu utilizo uma identação adicional.

Vamos para o seu exercício, primeiro veja todas as tabelas que se relacionam entre si e que você irá utilizar e faça os relacionamentos, **INNER JOIN**, **LEFT JOIN**, etc...

Eu não sei se está faltando alguma tabela no seu código mas não encontrei a tabela **ItensFactura**. Mas toda vez que você realiza o **INNER JOIN** você só irá trazer os dados se existirem nas duas tabelas, por isso não vejo necessidade de usar o **WHERE**.

No caso para utilizar o **WHERE** você deveria utilziar o **LEFT JOIN** que ele traz  todos os dados da tabela do **FROM** e só traz os dados da tabela do **LEFT** caso exista dados, senão as colunas virão em branco. Faça o teste.

No caso de se utilizar o **WHERE** com **LEFT JOIN** você deveria fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT cbal.NúmeroConta, cbal.Descrição, forn.Nome, forn.Localidade
FROM ContasBalanço cbal
  LEFT JOIN facturasacturas fac
    ON fac.ContaBalançoPredefinida = cbal.NúmeroConta
  INNER JOIN Fornecedores forn
    ON forn.IDFornecedor = fac.Fornecedor
WHERE fac.IDFactura IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY cbal.NúmeroConta ASC
```

Note o **WHERE**, **IS NOT NULL** significa que ele não irá trazer nada que for nulo, no caso as faturas que não foram emitidas.

E por ultimo ordenei os dados com o **ORDER BY ASC** (Ascendente) conforme o solicitado pelo exercício. o **ORDER BY DESC** ordena de forma decrescente, faça o teste.

Outra dica que dou ao iniciar no **SQL** é entender tudo que está fazendo, entender cada comando e pensar no que irá fazer antes de fazer, assim você aprende bem rápido. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelas dicas